# How to calculate Johnson Noise Voltage?

Tags: voltage, noise

I used [a Johnson Noise calculator to find the voltage of in a steel conductor](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-noise.htm), but it disagreed with the following calculation where $R = \frac{\rho \ L}{A} = \frac{7 \cdot 10^{-7} \ \Omega \ m \ \ 0.001 \ m}{0.001 \ m^2} = 0.0007 \ \Omega$.

$$\begin{align}
V &=k \ TR \\
&= 1.38064852 \cdot 10^{-23} \frac{m^2 kg}{ s^2 K} \times 275 \ K \times 0.0007 \ \Omega\\
&= 2.6577484 \cdot 10^{-24} \ V
\end{align}$$

The calculator in the first line says the scale is of $10^{-9}$ or so which is very different from $10^{-24}$. Which is correct?

Comment: A 10^15 difference seems like it's just a units problem. Have you checked the units on the calculator?

Comment: @probably_someone I took a look at them and the most noticable thing different was they used V=kRTdeltafrequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for Johnson-Nyquist noise is

$$V = \sqrt{4 \ k T \Delta f R }$$

Taking the square root of the value you calculated gives a value much closer to the calculator, $1.6 \cdot 10^{-12} \ V$. (Recalculating with the factor of $4$ added gives $3.3 \cdot 10^{-12} \ V$.)

Comment: I calculated V^2 thanks. The calculator also used DeltaFrequency in their calculation which explains why it is on the order of 10^-9 instead of 10^-12.  Would I need to worry about frequency for measuring the JN in a conductor?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395662/

Comment: The Nyquist noise formula $\sqrt{4 k T R }$ is in units of $volt/\sqrt{Hz}$ and not $volt$. The *actual* measured noise voltage must include a measurement bandwidth, say $B$, and then the measured rms noise is $\sqrt{4 k T R B}$ and *that* is in $volt$.